# Can write into the file in python and startswith not working

Tags: python, data-processing

I have a problem. I have a task "download by ID"

This is my previous program which download text (PDB file)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def download(inf):
    url = xxxxxxxxxxx   
    response = urlopen(xxx)            
    text = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    return data

new_download = download('154)
```

It works perfect, but my function that I must create, don't write to file lines which starts with num

```
from urllib.request import urlopen #moduule for URL processing

    with open('new_test', 'w') as a:
        for sent in text:  #for every line in sequences file
            if line.startswith('num'):
                line1.writeline(sent)
```

Comment: There is no `writeline` method. You want `a.write(line + '\n')`

Answer (score 3):

You're not iterating over the lines, you're iterating over the characters. Change

```
for line in data2:
```

to

```
for line in data2.splitlines():
```